# Cannot initialize type x with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am proving this code but it sends me the error about the collection initialize.

> Cannot initialize type x with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

I am trying this with MVC 5

```
private readonly List clients = new List()
   {
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 1, Name = "Julio Avellaneda", Email = "julito_gtu@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 2, Name = "Juan Torres", Email = "jtorres@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 3, Name = "Oscar Camacho", Email = "oscar@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 4, Name = "Gina Urrego", Email = "ginna@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 5, Name = "Nathalia Ramirez", Email = "natha@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 6, Name = "Raul Rodriguez", Email = "rodriguez.raul@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 7, Name = "Johana Espitia", Email = "johana_espitia@hotmail.com" }

    };
```

**My class List**

```
class List
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you have you own custom `List` class? Why not rather use [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) built in class?

Comment: The error seems pretty appropriate. Your "List" class is NOT an IEnumerable. List just seems to be an empty class called List. Maybe what you meant to do was use List<T>, such as: 
private readonly List<Pruebas.Models.Client> clients = new List<Pruebas.Models.Client>()

Comment: Those look like real email addresses. Are you sure they should be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `List<T>` from `System.Collections.Generic` instead of creating your own List class. Your list class is just an empty class. In order to achieve what you are doing, remove your list class, import the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` and use `List<T>`.

Here is your code using List

Remove your List class.

And then import System.Collections.Generic namespace like this.

```
Using System.Collections.Generic;
```

And then use following code.

```
private readonly List<Pruebas.Models.Client> clients = new List<Pruebas.Models.Client>()
{
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 1, Name = "Julio Avellaneda", Email = "julito_gtu@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 2, Name = "Juan Torres", Email = "jtorres@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 3, Name = "Oscar Camacho", Email = "oscar@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 4, Name = "Gina Urrego", Email = "ginna@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 5, Name = "Nathalia Ramirez", Email = "natha@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 6, Name = "Raul Rodriguez", Email = "rodriguez.raul@hotmail.com" },
        new Pruebas.Models.Client { Id = 7, Name = "Johana Espitia", Email = "johana_espitia@hotmail.com" }

};
```